# CSS - Display: table leaves whitespace

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a problem while using display: table; and display: table-cell; in CSS.

When the content of my left div is too big i made it so the content in the right div would adjust to the new size, only now it leaves big spots of whitespace where they do not belong.

**[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NLcNY/2/)**

Screenshots:

**Correct whitespace:**

[image: Correct spacing]

**Incorrect whitespace:**

[image: Incorrect spacing]

My CSS:

```
.module{
    width: 400px;
    display: table;
}

.module-info {
    display: table-cell;    
    border: medium dashed #03F;
}
.module-controls-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    border: medium solid #C00;
    text-align: center;
}

.module-controls{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 256px;
    display: inline-block;

}
.controls-group{
    position: relative;
    width: 124px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.module-button{
    width: 60px;
}
```

If anyone could tell me how to fix this it would help so much, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add vertical-align: top to .module-info

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NLcNY/6/)

```
.module-info {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;    
    border: medium dashed #03F;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `vertical-align:middle;` to `.module-info` and `.module-controls-wrapper`:

```
.module-info {
    display: table-cell;    
    vertical-align:middle;
    border: medium dashed #03F;
}

.module-controls-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border: medium solid #C00;
    text-align: center;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/NLcNY/5/)